# ADO recordset addnew datetime field fails

Tags: mysql, vba, datetime, ado, recordset

Here is the (quite simple) problem:

I open a MySql table as an ADO recordset (named for example "product"). Let's say the table has two INT fields (named for example "int1", "int2"), none of them has default value, so when I add a new record to the recordset, I have to provide those.

Up to this point, the code works fine, which is this:

```
product.AddNew Array("int1", "int2"), Array(1, 2)
```

(some other details of the code:

```
oConn.CursorLocation = adUseClient
product.Open sqlstr, oConn, adOpenStatic, adLockBatchOptimistic, adCmdText
Set product.ActiveConnection = Nothing)
```

OK, so the problem is, if I extend the table with on datetime typed column, everything fails, though I tried every kind of format that I could imagine.

```
product.AddNew Array("int1", "int2", "test"), Array(1, 2, "2014-01-01")
product.AddNew Array("int1", "int2", "test"), Array(1, 2, "20140101")
product.AddNew Array("int1", "int2", "test"), Array(1, 2, "'2014-01-01'")
product.AddNew Array("int1", "int2", "test"), Array(1, 2, dateserial(2014,01,01))
```

And so on ...

There error message is:
Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)':
The data provider returned with E_FAIL state

SO, what is the way of adding new record with datetime typed field, without default value?

Thank you, bye,
Istvan

OK, THAT IS SOMETHING ELSE!
I figured out that it is not about the datetime format. What I'm actaully trying to do is to add a new record to a PrestaShop 1.4 'ps_product' table, which is opened as an ADO recordset (see above)
That table has 3 fields, which do not have default values, but even if I use the correct formats, I still receive that same error message above

So this do not work:

```
tmp = ps_product.Fields("date_upd").Value
ps_product.AddNew Array("id_tax_rules_group", "date_add", "date_upd"), Array(1, tmp, tmp)
```

Any (new) ideas? :)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I think you can pass the date directly as a Date.

Comment: Well, does not work. (See the 4th try above) I actually tried that too.

Comment: okay, the only thing I can think of is the formatting for the Jet engine date is "#2014-01-01#", alternatively you could just oConn.Execute("INSERT INTO ...")